# Wordpress WPHide and Security enhance 500 error

Tags: wordpress

The plugin WPHide was installed by one of my clients and they changed the admin url to /customize and now the dashboard is giving 404 error on pretty much all the pages. I cannot access Plugins, Widgets, Pages etc on dashboard and I get '500 Internal Server Error'. How can I reset the admin url to wp-admin?

The website is fine, only the dashboard access is broken.

Plugin: [Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-security-enhancer/)

Comment: I'm going to take a shot at the dark, and guess you don't have a backup of the database before the change happened?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the plugin folder from the /wp-content/plugins/ directory?

Comment: I did have an automatic backup setup and reverted the site to a working version rather than having to mess with db etc.

Comment: Have you contacted the plugin authors and gone through the support tab on the Wordpress Plugin page?